# LinqtoSQL with a where clause containing a List?

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have researched this to death.  There does seem to be some answers here already, but frankly the answers confuse me.  So I'll try to make this as basic as possible.

If I have a table in a database, "People" with a name column(string) and an age(int) column.  Then I do something like this:

```
List<int> ages = new List<int>();
ages.Add(39);
ages.Add(40);
var result = from p in People
where ages.Contains((int)p.Age)
select p;
```

The syntax is passing, but returns nothing (both in VS2010 and LinqPad).  Shouldn't this make a SQL statement with a where clause containing the ages in my list?

Simple answer anyone?  (Ideally if you could modify my example and make it work.. that would be great!)

Comment: What is the datatype of p.Age? Can you post the resulting SQL-query, either with context.Log = Console.Out or from SQL Profiler?

Comment: By the way, is this linq2objects or linq2SQL?

Comment: Oh, I only casted the p.Age (which is an Int) because it is optional in the db.  Also, if you read above "People" is a database table but obviously ages is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are doing it as Linq2SQL, it appears you are doing it correctly in order to ensure the proper projections for SQL Server. You may try writing it a slightly different way, like:

```
var result = from p in People
where ages.Select(a => a).Contains(p.Age)
select p;
```

You say that it returns nothing. Are you sure that there are matching records to return? Also, are you using `result` anywhere? The query won't execute if you don't bind it to something or call `ToList()` to some other projecting interaction.

Sample from comments:

```
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var Merchandiser = (new DataClasses1DataContext()).Merchandisers;

var result = from m in Merchandiser 
where ints.Contains(m.Id) 
select m; 

foreach (var item in result) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(item.Name); 
} 

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Yes, I have 5 entries in the db.  5 people ranging in ages from 39 to 41.  I can't seem to get your syntax to function either.

Comment: In your example, the a in the lambda expression would be an int, which doesn't have a "Contains" definition

Comment: Sorry, must learn to finish the coffee before posting on SO

I spiked this and it works for me

    var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    var Merchandiser = (new DataClasses1DataContext()).Merchandisers;
    var result = from m in Merchandiser
                         where ints.Contains(m.Id)
                         select m;

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

So are you sure you are connecting to the DB and the resultant tables?

Comment: Weird.. I put this into visual studio in a new project and it worked... LinqPad still returns nothing, and my real project which is slightly more complicated returns nothing...

Comment: Edit your answer so it works and I'll mark this one answered (still need to know why the more complex one doesn't work.. (maybe I should post that on here?)